# OpenSource or paid JavaScript based file manager for Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, file-manager

Does anyone know of a good JavaScript based file manager that works with Amazon S3 Web Services. I need something like http://ckfinder.com, but that works directly with S3. Something like this would be great: `http://s3fm.com`[Editor note: this project disappeared]

I will need both upload and download and it would be nice to have some kind of integration with Amazon S3's ACL security.

I will be using this in an ASP.NET MVC project, so if it has any server side integration it would be nice if it was in .Net.

The only option I can come up with right now is cracking open the http://ckfinder.com code open and writing a plugin.

Comment: So why cant you use s3fm? We can discuss various licensing options if you need access/modification to the actual source code. Let me know s3fm@tollbit.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the filemanager from Core Five Labs:
http://labs.corefive.com/2009/10/30/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0/

I was able to quickly create a connector for Amazon S3 using .net.  I used the Affirma.Threesharp library for S3 access and did it with WebForms, I'm sure it wouldn't be too much different with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are javascript-based solutions:**

1. Frantic S3 Browser https://github.com/frc/Frantic-S3-Browser
2. S3 Bucket Browser https://github.com/juvs/s3-bucket-browser
3. Github has other projects as well.

**.NET Solutions**

1. DevExpress https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/FileManager/AmazonProvider.aspx
2. Telerik (a word of caution: I've used this and found it to be out-of-date to the point of being not usable.) http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/amazon-s3-filebrowsercontentprovider